# Android - How to post string parameters to server using okhttpclient?

Tags: android, http, post, okhttp

I want to post 2 parameters - device uuid, google id - to server. I use OkhttpClient, so I wrote code like this:

```
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        FormBody.Builder formBuilder = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("uuid", "123456789123")
                .add("google_id", "testgoogleid");

        RequestBody formBody = formBuilder.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://ip:port/signup?")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d("Response", response.body().string());
```

I knew that the Formbody.Builder was making http requests, but response.body().string() is :

> {"message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."}

how to send this two parameters to server using POST and OkhttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json;charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(url)
  .post(body)
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
return response.body().string();
}
```